# Venus gravity assist (and aerobraking) - How much delta-V can it add?

Tags: venus, gravity-assist, aerobraking

The Voyagers made a grand tour using the gravity assist of each planet. But Jupiter, with a 12 year orbital period, doesn't always line up to be useful for spacecrafts destined to further planets. Venus is much quicker on its feet, but light.

What have been the altitudes of spacecrafts' perijove and perikrition (a look up word for periapsis at Venus) to date? What kind of delta-V change could one achieve by passing by Venus as close as possible, on the way to say Saturn or Uranus? Could aerobraking at Venus be helpful in optimizing the velocity vector?

Comment: While making these 'as low as safely possible' would yield the strongest gravity assist, it would also thoroughly randomize the ejection angle. The actual altitude choice prioritizes ejecting the probe in the desired direction over maximizing delta-V gains.

Comment: aerobraking is unlikely to help much with an outer planets mission, since it dissipates energy and you are going to need that energy to get out of the Suns gravity well.  Could be useful for a Mercury or close solar mission though.

Comment: @SF. I don't understand why a close flyby would fling of a probe randomly. The location of Saturn is said to be determined within one kilometer now. Fantastically. And the distance to a spacecraft within a radio wavelength or so. My impression is that this needle's can be thread.

Comment: @SteveLinton I was thinking that a deflection of the velocity vector could be worth something in terms of delta-v. I wonder if at times a Venus flyby can give a better kick to the outer planets than an of Jupiter, or none.

Comment: @LocalFluff: The periapsis altitude causes change in ejection angle. Yes, you can foresee exactly where the lowest possible periapsis will eject you. The problem is your calculation will most likely result in "in a completely useless direction."

Comment: @SF Why would that be so? All directions are available at Venus, since it is in an orbit in the ecliptic plane. Venus gravity assists have been used to reach Mercury (Bepi Colombo) as well as Saturn (Cassini). I wonder how much of a delta-v change one can get by going as close as possible. Venus' orbital velocity is 2.7 times that of Jupiter, which compensates a little bit for having only 1/400 the mass of Jupiter.

Comment: @LocalFluff: You're completely missing the point. Your ejection angle has two components. One for orbital plane of your hyperbolic orbit of the flyby, and one for hyperbola eccentricity: whether it's closer to parabola, or closer to a straight line, if you exit 'on the other side' or 'turn around and get ejected back where you came from'. You modify the first through change of latitude at which you aim at arrival, which isn't much of an issue here. You modify the latter through change of periapsis altitude - distance of the flyby.

Comment: If you choose a very low periapsis, you get the most acceleration from the planet, but simultaneously your trajectory is curved the most. And you don't want your trajectory to be curved "the most", you want it curved "just the right amount".

Answer (score 2):

> *What have been the altitudes of spacecrafts' perijove and perikrition (a look up word for periapsis at Venus) to date?*

[HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) & Wikipedia ([Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_the_outer_planets#Jupiter) & [Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_Venus) & [Hyperbolic orbital mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory#Parameters_describing_a_hyperbolic_trajectory)) have most of the information needed to answer the first question. It's pretty straightforward for Jupiter:

| Mission: | $r_p$ (km, from center of body): | $\Delta V$ (km/s): |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Pioneer 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_10) | 203,300 | 15.3 |
| [Pioneer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_11) | 113,600 | 16.7 |
| [Voyager 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_2) | 722,900 | 11.5 |
| [Voyager 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1) | 348,500 | 16.3 |
| [Ulysses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_(spacecraft)) | 450,500 | 16.4 |
| [Cassini-Huygens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens) | 9,794,500 | 2.2 |
| [New Horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons) | 2,304,500 | 5.1 |

Where

$$\Delta V = \frac{2 \cdot v_{\infty}}{1 + \frac{r_p \cdot v_{\infty}^2}{\mu}}$$

([Source](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/6588/40257))

Venus is a solar system oddity; [it's hosted more missions than any other planet](https://www.vox.com/2015/3/9/8144825/space-maps), yet most of these came some 50 years ago and/or from the Soviet Union so their archiving leaves a lot to be desired. Consider that [NAIF only has trajectory data for Mariner 2](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/data_venus.html) (and not later Mariners at Venus).

Luckily "close approach distance" is a commonly touted parameter (even if of dubious origin). Additionally, knowing mission dates (*thus knowing planetary locations*) we can determine the Venusian flyby energy, $v_{\infty}$, and thus find the $\Delta V$. Instances where this was done are denoted in the fourth column (indirect):

| Mission: | $r_p$ (km, from center of body): | $\Delta V$ (km/s): | Calculation: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Mariner 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_2) | 41,000 | 2.3 | direct |
| [Mariner 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_5) | 10,000 | 4.8 | indirect |
| [Mariner 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_10) | 11,800 | 4.7 | indirect |
| [Venera 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_11) | 40,000 | 2.5 | indirect |
| [Venera 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_12) | 40,000 | 2.5 | indirect |
| [Venera 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_13) | 36,000 | 2.7 | indirect |
| [Venera 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_14) | 26,000 | 3.5 | indirect |
| [Vega 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega_1) | 39,000 | 2.8 | indirect |
| [Vega 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega_2) | 24,500 | 3.6 | indirect |
| [Galileo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_project) | 22,200 | 3.4 | direct |
| [Cassini Huygens, x2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens) | 6340, 6650 | 7.1, 6.7 | direct |
| [MESSENGER, x2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESSENGER) | 9040, 6390 | 5.5, 6.9 | direct |
| [Parker Solar Probe, x7!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe) | 8480, 9060, 6890, 8440, 9860, 10100, 6440 | 3.1, 2.9, 3.8, 3.1, 2.7, 2.7, 4.0 | direct |
| [BepiColombo, x2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BepiColombo) | 16770, 6600 | 3.7, 7.0 | direct |
| [Solar Orbiter, x8!!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BepiColombo) | 13500, 14050, 12650, 6550, 6830, 6400, 6400, 8710 | 3.5, 3.4, 2.6, 4.7, 4.5, 4.8, 4.8, 3.6 | direct |

For reference the radius of Jupiter and Venus are ~70,000 km & ~6050 km, respectively.

> *What kind of delta-V change could one achieve by passing by Venus as close as possible*

[This answer from Mark Alder](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/6588/40257) explains the shape of the curve well, there is an optimal $v_{\infty}$ value for maximum $\Delta V$ equal to the orbital velocity at the periapsis height ($\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r_p}}$). This is also equal to the maximum $\Delta V$ gained in the flyby. **For Venus at a height of 250km the maximum $\Delta V$ is 7.18 km/s.**

> *Could aerobraking at Venus be helpful in optimizing the velocity vector?*

In theory it could be helpful. It's noted [in this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10023/40257) that Cassini-Huygens's inner solar system deep space maneuver "*reduced* its heliocentric energy" so the idea of losing energy is not outright bad. However, this adds enormous complexity to a mission and it is not a mission enabling architecture (the same end results can be accomplished by other means).